# What are some metaphores about strong hatred?

Tags: metaphors

Just wondering how one can express one's utter hatred of something/someone in more elegant ways?

Comment: To whom? It makes a lot of difference.

Answer (score 1):

> "They are pure poison."

{eg ['How to Teach Poetry Writing' ...Michaela Morgan](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=joqsAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=metaphor+pure+poison&source=bl&ots=UAs60KPnkT&sig=Yc0ISm45lnPa_wpeKJaBaS9VDVY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2tsLOtLnUAhXKCcAKHdFbALoQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=metaphor%20pure%20poison&f=false)}

> *poison* [UNCOUNTABLE] words or actions that express the feeling of hating someone
>
> *The look she gave me was pure poison.*

{
[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/poison_1)}